# Flutter - Don't override a method to do a super method with the same parameters

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter `pubspec.yaml`, I updated my lint to 2.0.1 and now the following code gives me a warning

> Don't override a method to do a super method with the same parameters

```
 @override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
}
```

I see this same code frequently used on the net. Is it safe to just remove this code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are going to leave the method blank, you can remove it and it will not effect your app